# create a dictionary from variables of another dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary like the following:

```
{'invoice_date': '2021-02-12T15:48:52+05:30', 
'no_of_bill_files': '3', 
'amount': '12', 'gst': '12',
'bill0': 123, 'bill1': 456, 'bill2': 789, 'owner': 2}
```

I want to create a list by name `bill` which would contain data like this:

```
bill = [{'document':123},{'document':456},{'document':789}]
```

the number of dictionary depends upon the number of `'no_of_bill_files'` in the above dictionary

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you first dict name is `cond`:

```
>>> cond = {'invoice_date': '2021-02-12T15:48:52+05:30', 
'no_of_bill_files': '3', 
'amount': '12', 'gst': '12',
'bill0': 123, 'bill1': 456, 'bill2': 789, 'owner': 2}

>>> bill = [{'document': cond[f'bill{i}']} for i in range(int(cond['no_of_bill_files']))]
>>> bill
[{'document': 123}, {'document': 456}, {'document': 789}]
```

Here we use a [`list comprehension`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0202/), where the number of iteration is equal to `cond['no_of_bill_files']`.

```
>>> cond['no_of_bill_files']
'3'
# Now as it is in string, in order to use it in range
# we will need to convert it to int
```

Now for `range(3)`, the values after all the iteration will be `0, 1 and 2`, we add that to `bill` using [`f-string`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) and get the value from `cond` dict.

```
>>> for i in range(3):
        print(f'bill{i}')

bill0
bill1
bill2
```